Regarding Custom Approval process Update Case Comments
I have created a custom approval prcoess on a custom obejct in Salesforce and my requirement is to update comments on the ProcessInstanceStep Object, but as per documentation we can not perform DML on PrcoessInstance or ProcessInstaceStep Object. How to achieve this requirement?
